# How is ($\neg P \lor R$ ) $\land$ ($\neg Q \lor R$) equivalent to ($\neg P \land \neg Q) \lor R $

Tags: logic

How is ($\neg P \lor R$ ) $\land$ ($\neg Q \lor R$) equivalent to ($\neg P \land \neg Q) \lor R $ ?

I know this by making truth table but how to solve this using rules of logic ? Thank you

Comment: See [this proof tree](https://www.umsu.de/trees/#((%C2%ACP%E2%88%A8R)%E2%88%A7(%C2%ACQ%E2%88%A8R))%E2%86%94((%C2%ACP%E2%88%A7%C2%ACQ)%E2%88%A8R)).

Comment: Never heard of [Distributivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property#Propositional_logic) ?

Comment: @Shaun Thank you

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Sorry my mistake

Comment: @Shaun but this proof tree generator doesnot work for many formulas which are valid

Comment: Really, @JessicaGriffin? Like what?

Comment: @Shaun (p implies r) and ((p iff q) or (r iff q))

Comment: But that is not valid; see, [the proof tree generator gives a counterexample.](https://www.umsu.de/trees/#(p%20%E2%86%92%20r)%20%E2%88%A7%20((p%20%E2%86%94%20q)%20%E2%88%A8%20(r%20%E2%86%94%20q)))

Comment: @Shaun mt textbook question asks it to prove equal to (p implies q) and (q implies r )

Comment: [It works.](https://www.umsu.de/trees/#((p%20%E2%86%92%20r)%20%E2%88%A7%20((p%20%E2%86%94%20q)%20%E2%88%A8%20(r%20%E2%86%94%20q)))%E2%86%94((p%E2%86%92q)%E2%88%A7(q%E2%86%92r)))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use distributivity of $\wedge$ with respect to $\vee$.

Answer (score 1):

If you recast the formulas to use implication ($\rightarrow$), it's easier to see why this is true without having to resort to  mechanical approaches.
Because $$\neg P \lor Q \ \equiv P\  \rightarrow Q$$
the statement becomes: 
$$
(P \rightarrow R) \land (Q \rightarrow R) \ \equiv\  (P \lor Q) \rightarrow R
$$
Consider:

- P = Mary hasn't eaten,
- Q = Mary hasn't slept,
- R = Mary is unhappy.

Comment: Thank you . . . . .

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Saying false $<$ true (e.g. $\bot=0,\,\top=1$), you can restate this as$$p\le r\land q\le r\implies\max\{p,\,q\}\le r,$$which is trivial.